# Не работает ftp при включенном брандмауэре

Tags: windows, ftp

У меня windows 2008. Клиент ftps. При отключенном брандмауэре всё нормально работает. При включенном нет. Порты 20 и 21 в исключения внёс. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема?

Comment: Вот ей богу, как и на всех остальных форумах "НЕТ ТУТ Экстрасенсов, которые могут помочь по фотографии малевича".Явки, пароли, конфиги. ну как дети малые. Тут что за всех должны додумывать почему так а не иначе?что за брендмауер, роутер и прочая лабуда. ну не так же сложно один раз написать и получить ответ нежели постоянно давать инфу кусками.

Answer (score 2):

При работе в активном режиме, FTP-сервер с 20 TCP порта подлючается к клиенту сам, на порт, указанный в команде PORT. Варианта два:

1. разрешить в брандмауэре входящие TCP - коннеты с удаленного 20 tcp порта (не поможет, если FTP-сервер сам сидит за NAT устройством)
2. Использовать пассивный режим (тогда клиент сам будет подключаться к серверу в канале FTP-DATA)

Answer (score 0):

Порт 21 только для коннекта, сами данные обычно ходят в другом диапазоне, настраиваемом на сервере.

Попробуй в клиенте выставить "пассивный режим", а лучше на сервере выяснить или указать диапазон портов для данных и его тоже разрешить в брендмауэре.

Comment: В википедии [http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS][1] ссылаются на хауту [http://www.kaa.org.ua/statji/kak-nastroitj-v-total-commander-ftps-soedinenie.html][2], в котором описано подключение по ftps через total commander, там как раз настаивают на passive mode.   [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS  [2]: http://www.kaa.org.ua/statji/kak-nastroitj-v-total-commander-ftps-soedinenie.html